# Error setDate must implement interface DateTimeInterface symfony fixtures

Tags: fixtures, symfony5

I search in stackoverflow but i didn't find the answer.
I have this error :

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Matchs::setDate() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, bool given,

I have this in my fixtures :

```php
$match1 = new Matchs();
$m1->setDescription('Description ')
   ->setDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y hh:mm', '25-12-2001 20:30')) 
$manager->persist($m1);
```

So I don't understand why it does not work because I have implemented the DateTimeInterface interface...
Thansk for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime::createFromFormat` failed do create a DateTime, and in this case return `false`.

I belive that problem is the format, instead `'d-m-Y hh:mm'` try `'d-m-Y H:i'`

You can see a complete list of you can use in the format here https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php.